# Stop Evolution from making its own copy of a sent email

Tags: email, imap, evolution, sent-items

Whenever I send an email in Evolution from one of my @hotmail.com addresses (using IMAP), I always end up with 2 copies of that email in my Sent folder. The reason for this is because Hotmail/Outlook makes places its own copy of a sent email to the Sent folder, and so does Evolution.

Other email clients I use don't make their own copies of sent items, so I'm fine with Outlook/Hotmail doing that automatically, but I would like to stop Evolution from doing it. However, I can't seem to find the option to turn it off. The closest I can get is to make Evolution send copies to my computer's local Sent folder ("On This Computer/Sent") instead of to my email account's Sent folder. I found this under Preferences->Account Edit->Defaults.

Is it even possible to prevent Evolution from placing its own copies of emails to special folders like Sent and Drafts?

Comment: I reported an [issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/issues/171) for this...

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Settings, then just uncheck the sent folder option (instead of changing the location of where the copies are sent).

Now there is only one copy in your sent folder.

Comment: Evolution 3.22.6 doesn't have this option

Comment: This works under Evolution 3.30.5-1.1; look at Preferences / Account Edit / Defaults, as OP indicated. A small drawback is that Evolution stops displaying a nice “sent” icon next to the Sent messages folder when the box is unchecked.